# Image view Clickable in iPhone like Buttons

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem on how to make an image view behaves in the same way as a button.

Ex. at my .h file

```
-(IBAction)ClickTheImage:(id)sender;
```

then in the .m file.

```
-(void)ClickTheImage:(id)sender
{
//something to do with image click.
}
```

But when i try to connect the IBAction on my xib file, nothings happen when i try it to connect to my UIImageView. Any idea on how to do this?.

Comment: Why u want to use imageView it can be achieved using UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on your image view. Then create and add a gesture recognizer as follows:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTheImage:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
self.tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Make your class conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it the other way around. Create a *UIButton* and define the ImageView as background image of the UIButton. Then the connection between the IBAction and the UIButton will work..

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or why do you wanna use it the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use UITapGestureRecognizer

Add GestureRecognizerDelegate on .h file.
Suppose your ImageView is *img;

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *TapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ImageHasTouched:)];
[TapRecognizer setDelegate:self]; 
[img setUserInteractionEnable:YES];
[img addGestureRecognizer:TapRecognizer];


-(void)ImageHasTouched:(TapGestureRecognizer *)Recognizer
{
   UIImageView *TouchedImage=(UIImageView *)[[Recognizer self] view];
   //Now when ever your image will be touched this method will get fired.
   // do what ever you want
}
```